# SQL Server 2012 Spatial Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, spatial

I am trying to draw arrows. I know how to draw lines which takes me half way there but I want the tip to have a small triangle just like an arrow. However even when I use a triangle as a point, obviously it does not always point towards the direction of the line and might sometimes produce weird looking arrows.

I would like to draw the passes a player makes on a soccer field. I do that using LINESTRING and 4 coordinates I have in a table in my database. I use the xFrom, yFrom, xTo and yTo coordinates and I manage to draw lines. However I would like to have the tip of the line to show as an arrow but I found nothing in Google or in SQL documentation.

I would like to use SSRS and not any other graphics vector program because its simpler and its incorporated easily in my overall report.

Anyone can suggest a way of turning a line into an arrow?

Thanks

Comment: **1.** SQL Server is not a drawing tool! `geometry` and `geography` are not good data types to store any kind of vector graphics; these data types are meant for representing features in our physical world. OK perhaps you've drawn an arrow on the ground and want to represent this; in that case you'd probably construct it using a `MULTILINESTRING`. **2.** Please be more specific in your question. What exactly have you tried? What does your `SELECT` / `INSERT` / `WKT` geometry representation look like?

Comment: Ok sorry I am new at this....basically I would like to draw the passes a player has made on a soccer pitch. I managed to do so with linestring and xFrom,yFrom,xTo, yTo cordinates. Now I would like the line to be an arrow. I haven't tried anything regarding that because I have nothing in mind and Google doesn't seem to bring anything up when I search it.

Comment: Please put that information in your question (edit it; this information is relevant to your question), not in a mere comment! Please mention also why you want to do this with SQL Server. (After all, If all you need is a drawing, you could have used some kind of vector drawing software, or even MS Paint...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off I'd like to preface this answer with the statement that using SQL Server and Reporting Services as a graphics tool is asking for trouble.  This is by far, not what it was meant for.

With that being said, I believe this would work.  You will need to spend some time studying, though.  When manipulating images, you have several operations that you can perform.  (Like Rotating, skewing, resizing, etc.)  The mathematics behind these operations can be performed using matrix algebra.  What you will need to do is look at the line you have created.  It has a slope.  If you picture that line superimposed upon X and Y axes, you can see that there is an angle between the line and the Y axis.  (Assumes that the triagle's base rests upon the X axis.)  That angle is the angle that you will want to rotate your triangle that you're using as the tip of the arrow.  That should fix your problem.  You could create a formula to do the calculations.  (If the formula engine is robust enough to handle matrix algebra.)

Here are a couple of pages that give you the basics of how to rotate an image.

http://datagenetics.com/blog/august32013/index.html
http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/

Good luck!